# iCloud login within app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am building an app in Swift for iOS. I need the app to have a login so that users can store data in the cloud and sync between devices. Can I use their iCloud login, since they already have one set up if they've downloaded my app.

Or maybe somehow use the ubiquityIdentityToken as an identifier? (see code below)

```
func isICloudContainerAvailable()->Bool { 
    if let currentToken = NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken { 
        return true 
    } else { 
        return false 
    } 
}
```

I have searched the internet with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is what iCloud is for, to make it easy to sync data between the devices logged in with the same cloud id. You just need to save it to the cloud, with cloud kit and any other IOS or even OS X device will be able to access the same data.